# C++ Arrays, For Loop and String Data Types

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm trying to take in 4 strings into an array using a for loop. After that for loop finishes, I'm trying to display the 4 strings using a for loop. I don't know where my error is. Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//declare variables
string array[4] ;

cout<<"input 4 strings"<<endl;

for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    getline(cin,array[i]);
}
cout << "here are your 4 strings" << endl;

for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    cout<<array[j]<<endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;

} // end of main function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first loop should start at `i = 0`, not `i = 1`.

Comment: Thank you. I made the revision, but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @user3708219 For future reference it's always best to specify the error. That way it can help us narrow the problem.

Comment: @user3708219 What is the error?

Comment: I will keep that in mind. In my compiler, it shows no error, but when i go to compile the code, it fails. Sorry I can't provide the specific error

Comment: The code would not build

Comment: @user3708219 Okay. Please describe the behavior you are experiencing that leads you to believe that your code is failing.

Comment: I think it's the input on the array. Some syntax error. Looking up proper syntax for input strings into arrays with for loops. No luck so far

Comment: @user3708219 Nope. No syntax error. Your compiler would've displayed the error message. What is the actual thing that you're seeing that tells you your code is not working? (Note that your code works fine with me)

Comment: works for me too: http://ideone.com/dwQVWG

Comment: I think there was a bug in my visual studio software. I reinstalled the software, and the code compiled. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking in three strings,

```
for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    getline(cin,array[i]);
}
```

and printing four...

```
for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    cout<<array[j]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the revision, but even with the revision, I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @user3708219 What's the error?

Comment: code would not build. Sorry, but I don't know that specific error.

Comment: works fine for me: http://ideone.com/dwQVWG